# How to parse floats in pyparsing, including minus signs

Tags: python, floating-point, pyparsing

So I have the following strings (each string is a line of a .txt file) and I have built a parser to parse the first line as per follows:

`line1: " N1     0.00000000     0.00000000     0.00000000     Type    N      Rank   4"`

```
parser1 = Word(alphas + nums) + Word(printables + '.' + printables) + Word(printables + '.' + printables) \
                  + Word(printables + '.' + printables) + Word(alphas) + Word(alphas) + Word(alphas) + Word(nums)

result = (['N1', '0.00000000', '0.00000000', '0.00000000', 'Type', 'N', 'Rank', '4'], {})
```

Which is great. However, after this line follows just floats which may, or may not have minus signs, for example:

```
line2 = " -1.064533
      -0.000007      -0.130782       0.044770
       0.335373      -0.000007      -0.000006      -0.451296       0.378061
      -0.000034      -0.990753      -1.404081      -0.000067      -0.000150
                     -0.096208      -0.714299
      -0.017676       0.000019       0.000034       0.804011       0.911492
                      0.000019       0.000027       0.441683       0.107567"
```

And I've tried using the following parser to grab these numbers, but it unfortunately also will grab line1 also:

```
parser2 = Word(printables + '.' + printables)
```

Is there a way to parse floats, that may include the printable minus sign in a better way?

Thanks a lot (I'm new to pyparsing so be as harsh as you like)

Comment: Instead of rolling your own real number parser, you can use the one provided in pyaprsing at `pyparsing_common.real`. Full online docs can be found at https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Word(printables + '.' + printables)` does not do what you are thinking. `printables` is a string, so `printables + '.' + printables` evaluates to a *really* long string containing all the printable characters, followed by a period, followed by all the printable characters again. This string is then used to construct a `Word` object, which will match a space-delimited group of characters in the set of, well, all the printable characters (and since '.' is printable, then it is in that set already).

I *suspect* that what you really want to use to parse a real number with optional leading minus sign is something like

```
Optional('-') + Word(nums) + '.' + Word(nums)`
```

Note that the addition is done with the parse expressions, not the strings passed to Word. This will parse '-1.23' as `['-', '1', '.', '23']`. To get all that as a single string, wrap it in a Combine:

```
Combine(Optional('-') + Word(nums) + '.' + Word(nums))
```

Then you'll get '-1.23' from using that expression. It is still left to you afterward to convert that to a Python float using the `float()` builtin.

`pyparsing_common.real` is a pre-defined floating point parse expression that will handle leading signs, *and* convert from string to float at parse time, so that when you get the value from the parser, it is already converted to a float.